# PHP convert string with weeks and short month name to date

Tags: php, date

I am receiving JSON data with a date string with this format:

```
'Mon Jun 30, 2014'
```

What would be the way to convert this to a datetime? Checking the PHP functions for this I got unsecure if better to use [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/date_parse_from_format) or [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

What are the differences and which would suit better for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` would work well here. It allows you to format the string easily and also takes timezones into consideration when appropriate and can be easily used in comparisons without having to convert to a timestamp first.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d, Y', 'Mon Jun 30, 2014');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a unix timestamp using `strtotime()`.  I don't know what you mean by a "datetime", but if you mean something like for MySQL then you format the timestamp with `date()` (you can include time but it isn't present in the original string):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

The second of the two likely fits you better ---

The first one only breaks down the date into an array, so you can work with the parts, individually.

But the second returns the DateTime object you are looking for.